# scikit-learn Gaussian Mixture Model set prediction output based on Gaussian's mean

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I am using GMM to separate out 2 gaussians that overlap. One is the signal and the other one is the background. The background always has lower value and mean than the signal. Most of the time, the order of the `gmm.means_` is [lower_mean, higher_mean], which makes it predict 0 as background and 1 as signal. Sometimes, the order of the mean is [higher_mean, lower_mean], which makes GMM predict it as 0 for signal and 1 for noise (opposite of what I want). I want the gaussian with the lower mean to be background (0), and one with the higher mean to be signal(1). How can I set the GMM result to be in the correct order or how can I set the prediction output?

```
img = cv2.imread(path, -1)
img_flatten = img.flatten().reshape(img.flatten().shape[0],1)

gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
gmm.fit(img_flatten)
pred = gmm.predict(img_flatten) # how can I set the prediction value I want for each Gaussian?

print(np.round(g.means_, 2))
# gives [[  66.31] [ 203.64]] on some images and [[  67.32] [ 306.13]] on other
```

Answer (score 1):

The article of Stauffer and Grimson "Adaptive background mixture models for real-time tracking" discusses an heuristic to identify which of the components of a GMM corrspond to background. They propose to sort the Gaussians by the value of w/sigma (w are the mixture weights and sigma are their std's). And the first k ones should be the background ones. How to select k depends on each problem and is discussed in the paper.

But it your case of two Gaussians only, maybe you can check if the Gaussian component with highest w/sigma always corresponds to the same class.

One more detail: In that paper, sigma is the std of a 1-d Gaussian. In your case you seem to have N-dimensional Gaussians. In which case, instead of sigma maybe you can take the determinant of your covariance to the power of 1/2.